# Getting the year/month/day as a link in codeigniter calendar class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im trying to convert the a day to a link if there are any content so the format will be.

site/calendar/2012/1/2

so i will be able to retrieve the information that is relevant.

in my model in have the template and the other options,

[Model](http://pastebin.com/iy0jLMce)

and

[Controller](http://pastebin.com/j1Sw4BRa)

can someone please tell me how can i get the dates as year/month/day to the so i can retrieve the values.

```
<div class="content"><a href="year/month/{day}">View</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the month and year in your `view` method, so you could just pass those to the view through the `$data` array:

```
// Diary Controller
$data['calendar'] = $this->diary_model->generate($year, $month);
$data['year'] = $year; // ADD THIS
$data['month'] = $month; // ADD THIS

$data['body']='diary/calender';

$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

then, in your model you can set it like this:

```
// Diary Model
$this->conf['template'] = '...
{cal_cell_content}
  <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
  <div class="content"><a href="'.$year.'/'.$month.'/{day}">View</a></div>
{/cal_cell_content}
...';
```