# Make a link from the day in codeigniter calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.x version, and on one of my pages I want to display a calendar, in which, each day (equal or greater than today) will be a link.

My **controller** code looks like this:

```
 $prefs = array(
            'start_day'    => 'monday',
            'month_type'   => 'long',
            'day_type'     => 'short',
            'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
            'next_prev_url'   => base_url().'Hall/display_calendar/'
        );

        $prefs['template'] = '
            {table_open}<table class="call_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto;">{/table_open}
            {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}
            {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}
            {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}
            {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
            {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}
            {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}
            {cal_cell_start_today}<td>{/cal_cell_start_today}
            {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-month">{/cal_cell_start_other}
            // THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I AM TRYING TO CREATE THE LINK
            {cal_cell_content}<a href="'.base_url().'Hall/display_calendar/"{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
            {cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}
            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}
            {cal_cell_other}{day}{/cal_cel_other}
            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}
            {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}
            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
        ';
$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
```

And in the **view**, I have just this:

```
    echo $this->calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));
```

This code works, that is, the calendar is displayed, links for the next and previous months works just fine, however, no links are generated.

Sure enough, even if the code above worked somehow, all the days in the calendar will be links. I could live with that, but it will be best if I can manage to make the past days to not be links.

I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120176/highlight-some-days-in-codeigniter-calendar) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727504/getting-the-year-month-day-as-a-link-in-codeigniter-calendar-class#8729058) which are somehow related with my problem, but nothing worked here for me.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a comment but I don't have the reputation yet. Can I see the HTML for the calendar that was generated in the view? This could rule out any HTML quirks when the links are formatted.

Is there an extra quote here before {content}?:

```
a href="'.base_url().'Hall/display_calendar/"{content}"
```